# Tags in behat don't work

Tags: php, symfony, behat

I have:

```
windows 10
behat/behat                              v3.4.3  Scenario-oriented BDD framework for PHP 5.3
behat/gherkin                            v4.5.1  Gherkin DSL parser for PHP 5.3
behat/symfony2-extension                 2.1.4   Symfony2 framework extension for Behat
behat/transliterator                     v1.2.0  String transliterator
```

In behat.yml:

```
default:
    suites:
        test:
            filters:
                tags: "@ADMIN"
            contexts:
                - TestContext
```

And if I run:

```
behat --tags=@ADMIN
```

Then I have:

> No scenarios
>
> No steps

But if I remove from behat.yml:

```
            filters:
                tags: "@ADMIN"
```

And run:

```
behat
```

It's all fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can we see test code?

Comment: Do you have this tag `@ADMIN` added at scenario/feature level? If you are running using tags and not suite then you don't need this in the `yml` file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to specify the tags to run in command line, you need to remove the `@` symbol ([Behat docs](https://behat.org/en/latest/user_guide/configuration.html#global-filters)) from the comand line (BUT, keep it in the `.feature` file). You would run something like:

```
behat --tags=ADMIN
```